# How can I find out if boost::any contains a literal string?

Tags: c++, boost

I have this code

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>

std::vector<boost::any> a(  {1,2,3,"hello",3.0});
for (int i = 0; i < a.size();i++)
{
    if (a[i].type() == typeid(int)) // this works
    {
        std::cout << "int";
    }
    if (a[i].type() == typeid(char*)) // this does not work I know why
    {
        std::cout << "char*";
    }
}
```

What `if` statement should I use to detect `"hello"`, or any sized literal string?

Comment: `"hello"` this is string literal, so its type is `const char*`, try `typeid(const char*)`.

Comment: Note: if you're using `any::type`, and you're calling it more than once, you're using `any` wrong, and you should probably be using a `variant`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I find out if Boost any contains a literal string?

String literals are arrays of `const char`. `boost::any` stores decayed types, so string literal will be a `const char*`.

Note that there is no guarantee for the `const char*` to be a string literal. It can be a pointer to any character, not just the first character of a string literal.